# Static library inside vendor framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, static-libraries, vendor

I've currently a static library (.a file). I would like to embed this static library into a vendor framework (the goal is to get a dSYM to have a follow up on SDK crashes).

However I didn't succeed in exposing the .a library content into the framework.

Any option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I added a new target to my SDK project using `Cocoa touch framework` template (available since iOS 8) and it generates a dSYM file with the .framework file. Issue is solved.